# Заполнение шаблонного массива в С# (из консоли)

Tags: c#

Пусть есть вот такой простой шаблонный класс:

```
class Data<T>
{
    private int _count ; // кол-во элементов   
    private T [] data ; // шаблонный массив

    public Data(int count)
    {
        _count = count ;
        data = new T[_count];
        for (int i = 0; i < _count; i++)
            data[i] = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public Data()
    {
        _count = 0;
        data = null;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string chars = "";

        foreach (T element in data)
        {
            chars += element + " ";
        }
        return chars;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Data<int> data = new Data<int>(5);
        Console.WriteLine(data.ToString());

    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что при заполнении (вызове конструктора Data(int count) Console.ReadLine() возвращает строку и компилятор не может её привести к типу T). Вопрос, наверное, простой, но в интернете ничего, увы, не нашел. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Очевидно, что компилятор прав. Так как на обобщённый тип `T` не наложены [ограничения](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/d5x73970.aspx), то единственное, что можно делать с переменными данного типа это присваивать значение *только* данного типа, вызов методов `GetType()`, `Equals()`, `GetHashCode()` и `ToString()`.

В отличии, например, от **шаблонных** типов в С++, в .NET **обобщённые** типы существуют не только на этапе компиляции, но и исполнения кода, поэтому требуется гарантия того, что любые операции с типом T будут корректны.

Пусть T окажется во время выполнения (не важно как именно) типом `Int32`. Тогда строка

```
T foo = Console.ReadLine();
```

окажется некорректной, потому как отсутствует перегрузка метода `Console.ReadLine()`, возвращающая тип T, являющийся `Int32`.

Достаточно много информации касаемо .NET обобщений (generics) с примерами [есть на MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/512aeb7t.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

попробуйте следующие:

```
class Data<T> where T : IConvertible
{ 
    ...
    public Data(int count)
    {
        _count = count ;
        data = new T[_count];
        for (int i = 0; i < _count; i++)
            data[i] = (T)Convert.ChangeType(Console.ReadLine(),typeof(T));
    }
    ...
}
```

почитайте про [Convert.ChangeType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.convert.changetype.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Один из выходов такой: можно создать интерфейс, такой, что реализующие его классы должны иметь что-то для того, чтобы считываться из строки (например, метод Parse()). Затем сузить T до классов, реализующих этот интерфейс.

```
class Data<T> where T : IParsable
```